# Azure Active Directory B2C Error: The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Tags: django, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

Right after authenticating for my web app with Azure Active Directory B2C, I get the following error message:

The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

This error message comes up after successfully authenticating through the "Sign In", "Sign Up", and the new "Sign Up or Sign In" policies. I have two identical websites, one hosted by Azure through their "App Services", and the other hosted in IBM Bluemix. The Bluemix-hosted website authenticates fine without errors, but the Azure-hosted version is the one giving me the error.

I have also created a troubleshooting webpage so I can troubleshoot and narrow down the source of the problem. As soon as I add the Application Claim "User's Object ID", and only that claim, I get the error. The problem is, I need that claim, among others, for authenticating purposes, so I can't just simply remove that claim.

The troubleshooting webpage is here:

https://troubleshootb2c2.azurewebsites.net/

In that webpage, just click on "Log in" at the top-right corner, and you will be taken to an authentication page using the "Sign Up or Sign In" policy. Once you sign in or sign up, it will redirect to a valid URL (https://troubleshootb2c2.azurewebsites.net/auth) and show the error message in the form of a webpage.

My code can be found here, if the problem lies within my code:

https://github.com/edsfocci/troubleshootb2c2

Comment: To possibly help in troubleshooting, I have a similar app that authenticates fine if it is hosted in Bluemix, but shows the error if it is hosted in Azure App Service. Therefore, it isn't a browser problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import redirect in your views.py.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
```

Looking at the [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler), I can see that this response is coming back from Azure App Service (IIS / Django app) rather than the Azure Oauth workflow. If you visit https://troubleshootb2c2.azurewebsites.net/auth/ directly you would expect it to redirect to https://troubleshootb2c2.azurewebsites.net/ but you get a Django NameError instead.

[image: Fiddler request/response]

Comment: Good catch @Ryan. I made the change, but the error still shows up. I remove the query string, and it redirects me to '/' fine, but when I click on "Log in" again, the error comes back.